# Can't access a private member of a class from a friend function? 'ostream' is not a member of 'std'?

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading, std

So I'm writing a class for complex numbers and for overloading the << operator, in the header file I wrote

`friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Complex& a);`

which I later defined in other file

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Complex& a)
{
    out << a.real << " + " << a.imaginary << "*i";
    return out;
}
```

It tells me that I can't access a private member of a class, although I declared it as a friend function. Plus, I get this error " 'ostream' is not a member of 'std' ".
What can I do about these?

Comment: Did you `#include <ostream>` or `#include <iostream>`? Also your second parameter should be a reference to const.

Comment: Okay, now it doesn't give me an error about the 'ostream', but still it doesn't let me access the members of the class.

Comment: Before defining your `operator<<()`, the compiler needs to have visibility (e.g. by including appropriate headers) of both the class definition, and `std::ostream`.   This generally means a need to include the header that has the class definition and `<iostream>` before defining (implementing) that function.     The compiler does not try to infer definitions that it cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

Without full minimal working example it is hard to tell what causes the error. One possible error is that the signature of your friend declaration is different from the definition.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex {
public:
    Complex(double re, double im):real(re),imaginary(im){}
    // public interface

private:

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Complex& a);

    double real = 0;
    double imaginary = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Complex& a)
{
    out << a.real << " + " << a.imaginary << "*i";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Complex c(1.,2.);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Now, if you by have written

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Complex& a);
```

but outside you only have

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Complex& a) // <- const is missing
```

You'll get the compiler warning:

```
<source>: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Complex&)':

<source>:18:14: error: 'double Complex::real' is private within this context

   18 |     out << a.real << " + " << a.imaginary << "*i";
...
```